# getting syntax error when checking boolean value with 'If' statement

Tags: if-statement, syntax-error, pine-script, pine-script-v5, boolean-expression

I'm trying to detect 3 specific EMA crosses, assign them to boolean variable, plot them and set alerts when their conditions are true.

I have no problem detecting and plotting the 3 crosses when they occur but when I try to set alerts using 'If' statement to check boolean value = true, I get a syntax error at the if statement.

The error is:

> Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

I've tried a thousand different ways to get rid of the syntax error. How am I so stumped on a simple syntax error? Lol  I need a fresh set of eyes to look at this for me.  Maybe its obvious?

---

Code:

```
Continuationema = ta.crossover(ema2_, ema8_)
plotshape(Continuationema, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), location=location.abovebar)   

Bearema = ta.crossunder(ema1_, ema2_)
plotshape(Bearema, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.new(color.red, 0), location=location.abovebar)              

Bullema = ta.crossover(ema2_, ema3_)
plotshape(Bullema, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.green, 0), location=location.belowbar)             

// Set Alerts

If Continuationema
    strategy.entry("Continuation",strategy.long,alert_message="Uptrend Detected")
    alert("Uptrend Continuation Detected. EMA2 Crossing Over EMA8")
```

The syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation' appears at the above 'If' statement

Comment: It may be an indentantion error. Check: https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/end-line-without-continuation/

Answer (score 0):

It is you IF statement wich is not well written, you should not use Capital ( **I**f ) but :

```
if Continuationema == true
```